# vs code not installing on Chromebook

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, chromebook, crostini

I was trying to install vs code on Chromebook with Linux but i get it off the website and go into the file and it says "apt is not install able" and things like it for about five rows of text I hope someone knows the answer.

Comment: i tried to do it through the terminal as opposed to files and it still is showing and error i tried to reinstall the file and do it again but it still didn't work.

Comment: Can you please post the commands you executed and the output you got?

Answer (score 0):

Try beginning with sudo apt install as opposed to apt install.  Linux can be wishy washy when it comes to installs in the terminal.

Comment: that is true but i already usually do that and i was using files still won't work in terminal thanks for the answer though

Comment: No problem. If I can think of anything else, I will reach out

Comment: Here’s [instructions](https://wiki.debian.org/VisualStudioCode) on how to install VSCode on Debian from the Debian wiki. After reading it myself, I’ve been using [VSCodium](https://vscodium.com/), an open-source version of VS Code. Here’s how I installed it: [How to install VSCodium on Debian using Extrepo](https://gitlab.com/paulcarroty/vscodium-deb-rpm-repo#option-3-debian-only)